# Regex incluyendo acento en variables desde un input

Tags: javascript, regex

Como puedo hacer un replace a un texto en el cual se incluya las palabras que tienen acento y las que están en mayusculas, la información puede variar, y mediante el evento keyup se pueden filtrar cualquier palabra:

```js
const busqueda = 'informacion'
const texto = 'El carro va rapido buscanco informacion para cambiar las ruedas, esta Información es muy importante porque puede sufrir averias';
const regex = new RegExp('(' + busqueda + ')', 'gi');
const resultado = texto.replace(regex, '<span class=\'highlight-text\'>$1</span>');
console.log(resultado)
```

**Resultado esperado:**

```
'El carro va rapido buscanco <span class=\'highlight-text\'>informacion</span> para cambiar las ruedas, esta <span class=\'highlight-text\'>Información</span> es muy importante porque puede sufrir averias';
```

**Resultado obtenido:**

```
'El carro va rapido buscanco <span class=\'highlight-text\'>informacion</span> para cambiar las ruedas, esta Información es muy importante porque puede sufrir averias';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No es una tarea fácil, trataré de enumerar los pasos a seguir:

1. Normalizar la cadena de búsqueda para eliminar diacríticos (acentos, diéresis, etc)
2. Convertir en minúsculas para facilitar los pasos siguientes
3. Remplazar letras que pueden tener variantes, en este caso solo use la "o" y se remplazó por `[oóòö]`: Dentro de corchetes para especificar que puede ser cualquiera de esos caracteres
4. Obtener todas las coincidencias con [string.matchAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll)
5. Recorrer coincidencias para remplazar una por una, manteniendo mayúsculas y minúsculas como estaban originalmente

```js
// Debe ser variable para poder modificar
let busqueda = 'informacion';
let texto = 'El carro va rapido buscanco informacion para cambiar las ruedas, esta Información es muy importante porque puede sufrir averias. InfOrmaCiÓn';

// ****** NORMALIZAR LA CADENA DE BÚSQUEDA *****
// Tomado de la respuesta eliminada de @Dramaturgo
busqueda = busqueda.normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "");

// Convertir en minúsculas
busqueda = busqueda.toLowerCase();

// Agregar opciones para coincidir con cualquiera de las formas de la vocal "o"
// Se colocan entre corchetes para buscar cualquiera de ellas
busqueda = busqueda.replaceAll('o', '[oóòö]');
// Agregar para la "a"
busqueda = busqueda.replaceAll('a', '[aáàä]');

// Aquí deberías agregar el resto de vocales y, seguramente, la Ñ [nñ]

// Crear expresión regular
const regex = new RegExp('(' + busqueda + ')', 'gi');

// Obtener coincidencias, desesctruturando para poder manejar más fácil
let arr = [...texto.matchAll(regex)];
console.log(arr);

// Recorrer cada coincidencia para remplazar
arr.forEach(match => {
    // match es un arreglo de dos elementos, ambos iguales, usar el primero [0]
    texto = texto.replace(match[0], `<b>${match[0]}</b>`);
});
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<p>${texto}</p>`);
```

Aparte de realizar muchas pruebas, creo que la parte más difícil va a ser identificar todas las letras que pueden tener variantes; si es solo en español, pueden ser nada más vocales y ñ.

**Edición:**

Mencioné lo de las pruebas porque ya imaginaba que no iba a funcionar en todos los casos y, efectivamente, si la palabra se repite exactamente igual solo la primera se remplaza. La solución es crear un arreglo de coincidencias sin repeticiones y usar `replaceAll()` en lugar de solo `replace()`.

Respecto a lo que comentas en la edición de la pregunta:

> ... la información puede variar, y mediante el evento keyup se pueden filtrar cualquier palabra

Y el comentario:

> ... me gustaría saber si es posible dejarlo abierto para cualquier vocal con acento, pero de que manera lo podría hacer mas general...

Ten por seguro que agregando las otras letras a la expresión regular, va a funcionar para encontrar cualquier palabra, siempre que hayas considerado todas las opciones. La parte importante está en este bloque de código:

```
// Agregar opciones para coincidir con cualquiera de las formas de la vocal "o"
busqueda = busqueda.replaceAll('o', '[oóòö]');
// Agregar para la "a"
busqueda = busqueda.replaceAll('a', '[aáàä]');
```

Creo que es bastante claro lo que debes hacer para agregar las otras vocales.

Comment: no logro solventar esta parte `busqueda = busqueda.replaceAll('o', '[o|ó|ò|ö]');`, porque le coloque las variaciones con las vocales y no me funciono, me podrías orientar, esto con el fin de hacerlo dinámico

Comment: @Gdaimon, actualicé la respuesta para poner un ejemplo de cómo agregar otra vocal. Si no te funciona, edita tu pregunta para poner el código actualizado y tratar de ver qué es lo que está mal.

Comment: En efecto la solución funciona con las palabras que tienen acento en la ó, me dgustaría saber si es posible dejarlo abierto para cualquier vocal con acento, pero de que manera lo podría hacer mas general, debido a que la busqueda puede se por ejemplo con la palabra `nuñez`, pero otra busqueda puede ser `sí`

Comment: @Gdaimon, en la respuesta están las opciones para agregar "a" y "o", te toca agregar el resto de letras y variantes que quieras considerar.

Comment: Mil gracias...!

Comment: `[o|ó|ò|ö]` debería ser `[oóòö]` (sin `|`)

Comment: @Pollo, cierto, también funciona. Gracias por la sugerencia.

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```js
const removeAccents = text => text.normalize("NFD").replace(/\p{Diacritic}/gu, "").toLowerCase();

const busqueda = 'informacion'
const texto = removeAccents('El carro va rapido buscanco informacion para cambiar las ruedas, esta Información es muy importante porque puede sufrir averias');

const regex = new RegExp('(' + busqueda + ')', 'gi');
const resultado = texto.replaceAll(regex, '<span class=\'highlight-text\'>$1</span>');
console.log(resultado)
```